# Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsContextListener

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to run one of official spring examples gt-rest-service and always get an error.

> 2015-07-11 23:38:11.058  INFO 3833 --- [lication.main()]
>   s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with
>   port(s): 8080 (http) 2015-07-11 23:38:11.376  INFO 3833 ---
>   [lication.main()] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting
>   service Tomcat 2015-07-11 23:38:11.385  INFO 3833 ---
>   [lication.main()] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23 2015-07-11 23:38:11.551  INFO
>   3833 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :
>   Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext 2015-07-11
>   23:38:11.551  INFO 3833 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization completed in 2443 ms 2015-07-11 23:38:12.479  INFO 3833
>   --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/] 2015-07-11 23:38:12.484 
>   INFO 3833 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter:
>   'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*] 2015-07-11 23:38:12.485  INFO 3833
>   --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*] 2015-07-11
>   23:38:12.706 ERROR 3833 --- [ost-startStop-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context
>   initialized event to listener instance of class
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsContextListener
>
> java.lang.VerifyError: StackMapTable error: bad offset Exception
>   Details:   Location:
>       org/apache/tomcat/websocket/WsWebSocketContainer.createSSLEngine(Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLEngine;
>   @0: aload_1   Reason:
>       Invalid stackmap specification.   Current Frame:
>       bci: @121
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'org/apache/tomcat/websocket/WsWebSocketContainer', 'java/util/Map', 'javax/net/ssl/SSLContext', 'java/lang/String',
>   'java/lang/String', 'java/io/File', 'java/security/KeyStore',
>   'java/io/InputStream', 'java/lang/Throwable' }
>       stack: { 'java/lang/Throwable' }   Bytecode:

I hope somebody helps me out with the problem.

Comment: You should give more details about the code that gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Mostly java.lang.VerifyError occurs when you have compiled against a different library than you are using at runtime. So you need to check your library
2. Try restarting the IDE to get it to recognize the sync issue.

Comment: The solution to your problem is nothing to do with code its something else. Did you try the mentioned steps.

Comment: My code is very simple. I take it from spring.io :) I I try to compile with maven without any IDE. I checked the version of tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.23.jar in my jar file and in my locale repository - they are the same. It's works under Win7, and does't under ubuntu.@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return "";
    }
}

Comment: I get error 7205. 
[Loaded ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ClassPackagingData from jar:file:/home/pavel2107/gs-maven/gs-rest-service/initial/gs-rest-service/complete/target/gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar!/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/]
2015-07-12 14:50:25.529 ERROR 7205 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsContextListener

Comment: Yes, I understand it. The same code works fine on a different computers. I restarted IDE - nothing changed. What library should I check ?

Answer (score 0):

So just delete maven repository and everything will be Ok